# Do we need to use server_name in a 2nd server block if redirecting http to https nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

If i am redirecting all http traffic to https, should we use `server_name` on 443 block:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name domain.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        server_name domain.com; #do we need this?

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

Can i omit to write `server_name` in the 2nd server block under 443 port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need this because you could have (or add later) another server block that listens on 443. Then you need to tell nginx which server-block should serve requests to which domain.